# Raw use of parameterized class using class for name

Tags: java

I have this line of code

```
   Class c1 = Class.forName(BASE_PACKAGE_NAME + "." + appId + ".v" + version.replace(",", "") + NAME);
```

but I have the compilation Warning:

```
Raw use of parameterized class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the generic type.  You can use:

```java
Class<?> c1 = Class.forName(...
```

to silence the warning.